# MVC Razor EditorFor Last Object in List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, editorfor

I'm trying to display EditorFor for the last child Object in an collection. Below are the POCOs for the Order (Parent) and  Hold (child collection):

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ....
    public virtual List<Hold> Holds { get; set; }
}

public class Hold
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime? When { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my attempt at creating an Order view that shows an Order and the last Hold if there is one present. I've commented out the last Hold attempt that doesn't work.

```
@model Order

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
{
   <div class="form-group row">
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "col-xs-2" })
      <div class="col-xs-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-xs-2">When</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
         @*@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Holds.Last().When, new {})*@
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

The Holds collection can also be null so doing Last() in that case will case an null exception even if that did work.

This seems like something simple and I have this pattern in a couple places in my database. Can anyone recommend a good way to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: do you need editors for every field in `Hold`?

Comment: No I just need an editor for the DateTime field of the last Hold in the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a view model for this because you wont get a very good response in your HttpPost action when you post this back

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        Order = new Order();
        Hold = new Hold();
    }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Hold Hold { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

    var o = from o context.Order.Include("Holds").Single(id);
    var model = new OrderViewModel()
    {
        Order = o
    }
    if (o.Holds.Count() > 0)
        model.Hold = o.Holds.Last();
    return View(model);
}
```

then just use EditorFors

```
@model OrderViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
{
   <div class="form-group row">
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Order.Name, new { @class = "col-xs-2" })
      <div class="col-xs-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Order.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-xs-2>When</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Hold.When)
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Jamie, I've known about ViewModels but never knew when or why to use them until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of using `Last()` you should use `LastOrDefault()` and then do proper null-checking. `Last()` raises an exception is nothing is found, while `LastOrDefault` simply returns null in that case.

Second, using `Last()` or `LastOrDefault()` will not generate the proper input names via `EditorFor`, so once you post, the modelbinder won't know what to do with the value. Instead, you need to use indexing:

```
@if (Model.Holds.Any())
{
    var lastIndex = Model.Holds.Count() - 1;

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xs-2">When</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Holds[lastIndex].When, new {})
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: this wont really post back anything for `Holds.When` unless the `lastIndex = 0`

Comment: Thanks for this.. I sort of forgot you could actually program in the view. I tried this and it needed a null check to start out and it leaves no Editor control if Holds is empty. And I'm not sure how to post back.